# Unexpected Regex Behavior PHP

Tags: php, regex

So I'm admittedly not that familiar with regex, but I'm trying to pull currency from a string.

I've tried a bunch of regexes that are supposedly "for" PHP but nothing seems to be working.  So I went back to the basics.

Pattern

```
\$\d*
```

String

```
2009 Low Price -- One Owner $8800 OBO
```

I was able to test/verify this pattern via http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6eJ

But when I run

```
    $pattern = "/\$\d*/";
    $match = preg_match_all($pattern, $this->Title, $matches);
    echo $matches[0][0];
```

I get no results... I have also tried using

```
$pattern = "/\\$\d*/";
```

and

```
$pattern = "/\\$\\d*/";
```

Anyone know why this is happening? Or am I missing something really obvious?

EDIT

Using PHP 5.5.11, on OSX I'm thinking it's an instance specific..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern to match the currency value

```
~\$\d+~
```

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$data = "2009 Low Price -- One Owner $8800 OBO";
$regex =  '~\$\d+~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "$8800"
  }
}
```

Comment: This still returned no results

Comment: it works for me. Could you paste the code in ideone?